# Como capturar dados de um gps conectado em php

Tags: php, gps

Estou tentando desenvolver um sistema de rastreador. Consegui a conexao do gps com meu servidor php. Só que sou leigo no assunto e não sei como capturar as msgs que o gps me envia. Alguem pode me ajudar?

Segui esse [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054291/how-to-listen-to-a-tcp-port-using-php) e consegui fazer o gps conectar.

Segue o código que usei.

```
require_once('/webserver/production/htdocs/assets/SocketServer.class.php'); // Include
$server = new SocketServer("192.168.1.4",5008); //Criar um servidor de ligação para um determinado endereço IP e ouvir a porta 5008 para conexões
$server->max_clients = 10; // Número de conexoes simultanea permitido
$server->hook("CONNECT","handle_connect"); // Executa a funcao handle_connect cada vez que alguem se conecta
$server->hook("INPUT","handle_input"); // Executar handle_input sempre que é enviado um texto para o servidor
$server->infinite_loop(); // Inicia o servidor

function handle_connect(&$server,&$client,$input){
    $this->db->query("insert into teste (texto) values ($input)"); ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"String? ","");
}

function handle_input(&$server,&$client,$input){// tratar entrada aq
    $trim = trim($input); // removendo espaços no texto de entrada

    //$this->db->query("insert into teste (texto) values ($trim)");///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if(strtolower($trim) == "quit"){ // Parar servidor
        SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"Ok! Goodbye..."); // Give the user a sad goodbye message, meany!
        $server->disconnect($client->server_clients_index); // Disconecta o cliente
        return;
    }

    $output = strrev($trim); // inverter string
    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,$output); // envia o texto invertido
    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"String? ",""); // solicitar outro texto
}
```

Comment: Qual gps, marca, modelo, tipo de conexão?

Comment: GPS VDO RASTREAR EVOLUTION. CONEXAO 3G/4G (GPS) WEBSERVER UBUNTU.